# Accessing JSON elements in a Scala Map

Tags: scala

How do I retrieve the value of the key "name" in the following code:

```
 import scala.util.parsing.json._

 val result = JSON.parseFull("""
   {"name": "Naoki",  "lang": ["Java", "Scala"]} 
 """)

 result match {
   case Some(e) => println(e) // => Map(name -> Naoki, lang -> List(Java, Scala))
   case None => println("Failed.")
 }
```

When I use `e("name")`, I get

```
error: Any does not take parameters
case Some(e) => println(e("name")) // => Map(name -> Naoki, lang -> List(Java, Scala))
```

Unwrapping with `println(result.flatMap(_.get("name")))` gets me:

```
error: value get is not a member of Any
println(result.flatMap(_.get("name")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.parsing.json.JSON%24) for `parseFull` say:

> def parseFull(input: String): Option[Any]
>
> Parse the given JSON string and return either a List[Any] if the JSON
>   string specifies an Array, or a Map[String,Any] if the JSON string
>   specifies an object.

So, if you change your `match` to look for the `Map[String, Any]` case, like so, then you can call its methods:

```
result match {
  case Some(m: Map[String, _]) => m("name")  // or m.get("name") for an Option
  case _ => sys.error("Failed.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work...just edited my question with the results.